# Seaborn lmplot change errorbar thickness and add caps

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization

I have the following dataframe and using seaborn LM plot to visualise some regression:

```
{'person': {0: 'mark',
  1: 'mark',
  2: 'mark',
  3: 'mark',
  4: 'mark',
  5: 'mark',
  6: 'mark',
  7: 'mark',
  8: 'mark',
  9: 'mark',
  10: 'mark',
  11: 'mark',
  12: 'mark',
  13: 'mark',
  14: 'mark',
  15: 'sue',
  16: 'sue',
  17: 'sue',
  18: 'sue',
  19: 'sue',
  20: 'sue',
  21: 'sue',
  22: 'sue',
  23: 'sue',
  24: 'sue',
  25: 'sue',
  26: 'sue',
  27: 'sue',
  28: 'sue',
  29: 'sue'},
 'energy': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 5,
  4: 5,
  5: 5,
  6: 10,
  7: 10,
  8: 10,
  9: 20,
  10: 20,
  11: 20,
  12: 50,
  13: 50,
  14: 50,
  15: 0,
  16: 0,
  17: 0,
  18: 5,
  19: 5,
  20: 5,
  21: 10,
  22: 10,
  23: 10,
  24: 20,
  25: 20,
  26: 20,
  27: 50,
  28: 50,
  29: 50},
 'result': {0: 2,
  1: 3,
  2: 1,
  3: 5,
  4: 8,
  5: 3,
  6: 14,
  7: 19,
  8: 10,
  9: 35,
  10: 42,
  11: 27,
  12: 74,
  13: 63,
  14: 79,
  15: 17,
  16: 22,
  17: 12,
  18: 25,
  19: 21,
  20: 19,
  21: 37,
  22: 32,
  23: 41,
  24: 64,
  25: 45,
  26: 51,
  27: 83,
  28: 74,
  29: 81}}
```

I can plot this data with a regression line as follows:

```
plt.figure()
a=sns.lmplot(data=df, x='energy', y='result', hue='person', x_estimator=np.mean, x_ci='sd', order=2, ci=None, line_kws={"lw":2})
```

I can change the thickness of the regression line using line_kws{"lw":2} and adjusting the number to change the thickness. I can also alter the size of the markers with scatter_kws{"s": 2}.

But, how do I change the thickness of the error bars, and add a cap on the end of them?

Comment: I guess this option isn't provided at the moment.  Please note that you shouldn't call `plt.figure()` as `sns.lmplot()` is a figure-level function and creates its own figure.